# Google App Script : How to copy and paste data from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy and paste some data one after the others from one sheet to another with a google app script. The thing is that my script doesn't paste the data on the correct row. I would like it to paste the first data in cell A2. Then, when I run the script again, in cell A3 etc.  But when I run the script, it pastes the data in cell A266

```
function Agregation () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Données');
var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classement');
var lr = ts.getLastRow();
Logger.log(lr);
ss.getRange('A2:E7').copyTo(ts.getRange('A0'+(lr+1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: I just tried your code with a sheet of my own and it worked as intended, could you share your sheet to see what might be causing the error? also, on `copyTo(ts.getRange('A0'+(lr+1))` you're adding lr+1 to "A0" so it's gonna be seen like a string, so the actual range will be "A0someint". Instead you should just leave it as `... ts.getRange('A0'), ...`

Comment: thanks for your answer @AlbertoMolina ! it seems that a cell wasn't empty, the Logger.Log showed that the Last Row was cell A265, weird because it was empty when I checked but I cleared up the sheet and it worked afterwards

Comment: Glad to know it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For documentation purposes.

The code was good, but the "Classement" sheet was not empty, since it had a non-empty cell at 'A265', the call to `ts.getLastRow();` was returning 265. After clearing the sheet and running the code it was working as intended.

A way of moving forward could be to call `ts.clear()` before the copy is done to ensure the sheet is empty.

**UPDATE**

After testing, updated the code in the following way:

```
function Agregation() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Test données');
  var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Test script');
  var lr = ts.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lr);
  ss.getRange('A2:E7').copyTo(ts.getRange('A'+(lr+1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  var toDelete = ts.getRange("A" + ts.getLastRow() - 3 + ":A" + ts.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if (toDelete[i][0] == ""){
      Logger.log(i);
      ts.deleteRow((ts.getLastRow() - 3) + i);
    }
  }
};
```

It adds the first line and then checks the next 3 to see if it is "", if so, it deletes the rows, so on the next run there wont be spaces

Comment: I am copying cells which contains this formula : IF(ISBLANK(E2);" ";TODAY()) from cells E2 : E7 in "Données" sheet. That is why "Classement" sheet wasn't empty, but ts.clear doesn't seem to work (or i am not doing it the right way)

Comment: Call `ts.clear()` on the line before you call `var lr = ts.getLastRow();` and it should work

Comment: Actually it's working but it's cleaning the whole sheet, and I would like to keep the old data and just deleting the empty rows

Comment: what do you mean with deleting the empty rows?

Comment: When I am copying cells that contains the formula :  IF(ISBLANK(E2);" ";TODAY()), in "Classement" sheet, it pastes cells that contains " ", which seem empty but they are not. That's why when I run my script, my data are pasted in the wrong cells. I would like to clear the cells that contains " ". Sorry if it's not very clear...

Comment: I understand what you mean, when you do the copy, the cells with the formula (that get copied) get copied as "", and that's what you want to remove and what appears as content in the second sheet, correct? if this is the case, could you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: yes, exactly ! This is the link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10RjB0fODUQqwhpt5jgWSN-7CvdWIdgJLOzCYWh-m4v8/edit#gid=953368669 (I changed the cells name by the way ; "Données" is now "Test données" & "Classement" > "Test script"

Comment: perfect, but you need to allow permission, click the share button on the top-right-> get shareable link and allow edit permission (if it's just view I cannot see the script)

Comment: Ok I'm seeing the issue, if you know if it's always going to be 4 rows you can get the range with `ss.getRange('A2:E2')` for this case

Comment: just tested that and it picks up just one row, can you not pick up just the first one or do you absolutely need the ones with the formula?

Comment: they are part of a supermetrics query that refresh itself everyday. They are empties today but tomorrow they might be non-empties.

Comment: got it, is the range to copy always going to be 'A2:F7'?

Comment: "A2:E7" yes - always

Comment: I updated and tested the code, it is working now, it adds the first line and then checks the next 3 to see if it is "", if so, it deletes the rows, so on the next run there wont be spaces